# Restrict access to users from selecting a database

Tags: amazon-athena

How do I use athena workgroups to restrict access of a user to a particular database?

For e.g. I have a user "readonly" who should not be able to run select query on default database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to restrict users from querying tables is to use IAM permissions. The permissions model in Athena is unfortunately more complicated than in an isolated data warehouse or RDBMS, since Athena is a part of a larger ecosystem that also includes S3 and Glue.

There is no specific permission for running `SELECT`. You can restrict users to run queries by controlling whether or not they are allowed to perform the `athena:StartQueryExecution` action, but you can't control what kind of queries they run.

Instead you need to think in terms of access to data, and access to the catalog.

To restrict reading you restrict the user's access to the data on S3. Even if a user is allowed to run a `SELECT` query they will get an error if they don't have permission to run `s3:ListObject` and `s3:GetObject` on the objects in the table's prefix.

You can also restrict a user's access to the catalog objects, i.e. the databases and tables – but that does not restrict their access to the data itself, think of it more as a restriction on creating, updating, and dropping databases and tables. Even if there is a way to restrict which databases and tables a user can see in the catalog, if they have permission to read the data they can read the data directly from S3 and skipping Athena.

You can find the documentation on how  to control access to catalog objects here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html

Workgroups in Athena can't be used to control access to data, nor to the catalog.